# ISNULL(col,0) and "notexists(col,0)"

Tags: mysql, isnull

In this Query (a simple example, my real query is more complex)

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(Quantity, 0)) from Product_SalRec where Date between '1-20-2013' and '1-25-2013'
```

or just

```
SELECT isnull(id,0) from table_1 where id = 123456789
```

it returns a "blank" column, cause rows doesn't exists in that range... even when using Isnull(),
i already tried --CASE when '' then 0--, but is not working for me.
is there a function to show 0 instead of blank?

Comment: try using ifnull instead of isnull?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(Quantity, 0)) from Product_SalRec where Date between '1-20-2013' and '1-25-2013'.
```

According to [the mysql reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) isnull() checks if an argument is null.